rust-analyzer macro-error "failed to load file" when using Sailfish TemplateOnce
I am using Sailfish as template engine in Rust:
https://rust-sailfish.github.io/sailfish/getting-started/
I followed the simple tutorial and have the following code:
#[derive(TemplateOnce)]
#[template(path = "index.stpl")]
struct HomeTemplate {
    messages: Vec<String>
}

let ctx = HomeTemplate {
    messages: vec![String::from("foo"), String::from("bar")],
};

println!("{}", ctx.render_once().unwrap());

The code itself works fine and the program runs fine.
However, VSCode has this constant error and the #[derive(TemplateOnce)] line is underlined in red:

failed to load file `/Users/XXXXXXXX....XXXX/server/target/debug/build/sailfish-compiler-19a8f501817d4158/out/templates/460671ab72c8d6b8-8a0fdd098792c13e`
rust-analyzer macro-error
core::macros::builtin
macro derive

It seems like something is wrong with my VSCode or my rust analyzer? I am not sure.
I tried cargo clean but the issue has persisted. Also tried restarting VSCode.
EDIT: Is my issue similar to the one this person is facing with include! macro gives failed to load file error?:
https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-analyzer/issues/17828
Or could it be similar to this?
https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-analyzer/issues/10647
EDIT 2: Looks like others are facing this too:
https://github.com/rust-sailfish/sailfish/issues/157

This occurs because when rust-analyzer starts, it loads the .rs files only. Since sailfish compiles the templates into files without any extension, it is not found by rust-analyzer.
It is not a limitation for the compiler as it can load any file it wants.
If you simply close the open file from the editor, the error vanishes.

Is there a workaround to prevent this error? Also, even when I close the file from VSCode editor, the error is still there for me.

As far as I know, there is no known work around. This can be resolved when either sailfish creates and uses .rs files or rust-analyzer loads non rs files.
